# $\{f_n\}$ be a normal family on $V$ s.t. $\{z \in V : \lim _{n\to \infty} f_n(z)$ exists $\}$ has a limit point in $V$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, normal-families

Let $V \subseteq \mathbb C$ be an open connected set , $\{f_n\}$ be a normal family on $V$ such that $\{z \in V : \lim _{n\to \infty} f_n(z)$ exists $\}$ has a limit point in $V$ . Then is it true that there is a function  $f:V \to \mathbb C$ such that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on each compact subset of $V$ ?

Comment: Yes. It's Vitali's theorem.

Comment: @ts375_zk26 : can you please provide a proof of it , or some reference with a proof of it ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry. Typo in my answer is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\{f_n\}$ is a normal family, every subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ has a subsequence which converges uniformly to some analytic function $f$ on each compact subset of $V$.
Suppose that another subsequence converges to $g$. Then $f(z)=g(z)$ for $z \in E$, $E=\{z\in V:\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(z) \text{ exists}\}$, implies $f=g$ by uniqueness principle. In other words, every converging subsequence converges to the same $f$.

Suppose that ${f_n}$ does not converge uniformly to $f$ on each compact subset. Then
\begin{align}
\exists  \varepsilon >0, \exists  \text{ compact }\Delta \subset V, \exists  \{z_k\}, &z_k\in \Delta ,\exists  \{f_{n_k}\} \\
&\text{ such that } |f_{n_k}(z_k)-f(z_k)|\ge \varepsilon \quad (k=1,2,...).\tag{1}\end{align} 
However, since the family is normal, $\{f_{n_k}\}$ has a subsequence $\{f_{n_k^\prime}\}$ which converges to $f$ uniformly on $\Delta $. This contradicts $(1)$.

[Typo fixed]